# VisualSVN Server for Eclipse Subversion Plugin ?

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

I have installed Eclipse Subversion Plugin . I also need a Subversion server , if I install VisualSVN Server , do I encounter any problems? Or do you recommend any other server? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with VisualSVN Server. If you have to install a SVN server on Windows; it is one of the best choices and you won't have any problem accessing it through the Eclipse IDE client plugin.